# Achieving Exactly-Once Processing in Spring Kafka for Bulk Events

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on a Spring Kafka application where I produce bulk events to Topic A (List<'Sms>). The goal is to achieve exactly-once processing throughout the entire flow, including consumption from Topic A, processing, and producing to Topic B one by one (Sms). I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Producer Side: To ensure exactly-once delivery from the producer, I have enabled idempotent production (enable.idempotence=true,transactional_id_config="transaction-event-id") and transactions. Is this setup correct for producing bulk events to Topic A?
2. Consumer Side: On the consumer side, I'm consuming messages with isolation.level=read_committed to ensure that only committed messages are processed. Is this sufficient for achieving exactly-once processing?
3. REST Call to External Service (Sms-Sender Microservice): After processing, I make a REST call to an external service (Sms-Sender microservice). How can I ensure at least-once semantics for this external call or default is exactly-once? Should I consider logging (write every success rest call to db and check if event is exist don't call)  and deduplication strategies or is there a recommended approach?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Kafka Streams but separately Producer/Consumer then further considerations take into account:

1. Before use the producer, please call `producer.initTransactions();`. It will prepare your producer for transactions use. Mentioned configs are valid.
2. For the consumer you need also define `enable.auto.commit=false` to be able manually commit offsets. When the consumer polled the messages the processing result and offsets should be stored in an atomic operation, otherwise it may not work properly. For example, if the message processing result need to be send into some another topic, then you should send it with offsets in the same transaction from the consumer side.
3. The actual approach depends on how you are processing requests on the SMS Sender service side.

I can advise next simple approach:

Each message assign with unique UUID, the SMS Send service will be able to check if the message has been seen before and decide what to do. If it is already sent - then may return just OK and do nothing, otherwise retry to send in case of fail.

*NOTE:* Please refer to the source with good Kafka message guarantees explanation with implementation details: https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/processing-guarantees-in-kafka-12dd2e30be0e

Comment: 1.I use KafkaTransactionManager with @Transactional.2.this flow exactly once except last consumer.Thanks for article.

Comment: Looks like you are using  Spring Boot implementation that is not mentioned in the question. So the answer is given if you are using plain Producer/Consumer :)